# How can the F_beta score with a search for the best threshold be implemented as a metric in tf.keras?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, metric

I'm trying to implement a custom metric in TensorFlow using the Keras API. The metric will be used on a binary classifier with one single output node. On a single evaluation, the metric is supposed to calculate the [F_beta score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score#F%CE%B2) of the model on a fixed range of thresholds, e.g., on the range `np.linspace(0, 1, 21)`. Then it returns the maximum of these F_beta scores. beta is given as a parameter to the metric.

I tried to implement it for several hours, but it still doesn't work. The latest error message that I'm receiving is

```
TypeError: tf.Graph captured an external symbolic tensor. The symbolic tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' created by node 'IteratorGetNext' is captured by the tf.Graph being executed as an input. But a tf.Graph is not allowed to take symbolic tensors from another graph as its inputs. Make sure all captured inputs of the executing tf.Graph are not symbolic tensors. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values for more information
```

I'm not really understanding what this error message means in this particular context, even after reading the linked guide. I would be very thankful if someone could show me how the correct implementation would look like, and maybe even explains why my implementation didn't work.

My code:

```
class FBeta_with_best_threshold(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    
    def __init__(self, beta=1, name='fbeta_with_best_threshold', dtype=tf.float32 ,**kwargs):
        super(FBeta_with_best_threshold, self).__init__(name=name, dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
        self.beta = beta
        self.y_true = None
        self.y_pred = None
        
        
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        if self.y_true is None and self.y_pred is None:
            self.y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
            self.y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, self.dtype)
        elif (not self.y_true is None) and (not self.y_pred is None):
            self.y_true = tf.concat((self.y_true, tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)), axis=0)
            self.y_pred = tf.concat((self.y_pred, tf.cast(y_pred, self.dtype)), axis=0)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('The object is in an invalid state')
            
    
    def fbeta_score(self, y_true, y_pred):
        precision = self.precision(y_true, y_pred)
        recall = self.recall(y_true, y_pred)
        
        return (1+self.beta**2)*(precision*recall)/(precision*self.beta**2 + recall)
    
    def precision(self, y_true, y_pred):
        true_positives = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        number_true_positives = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(true_positives, tf.int8))
        number_positives = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(y_pred, tf.int8))
        
        return number_true_positives/number_positives
    
    def recall(self, y_true, y_pred):
        true_positives = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        number_true_positives = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(true_positives, tf.int8))
        number_trues = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(y_true, tf.int8))
        
        return number_true_positives/number_trues
        
    def result(self):
        best_thresh = 0
        best_score = -1.0
        totry = np.linspace(0,1,21)
        for thresh in totry:
            score = self.fbeta_score(self.y_true, tf.cast(self.y_pred > thresh, tf.bool))
            if score > best_score:
                best_score = score
                best_thresh = thresh
        return best_score
    
    def reset_states(self):
        self.y_true = None
        self.y_pred = None
```